Creating a Scheduled Task for all users running with an Admin account at logon
I am trying to create a scheduled task that runs a batch file that will run at logon for any user that logs into the machine, and I also need it to run using a service account (that is an administrator account) as the users logging in will not be admins on the machine.
I have added the task running as the admin account, at log on.
I see a few issues:

The batch file is not running when I run the task.
The task only shows up in the Task Scheduler Library under the login which I created the task.

If I log in as another user, it is not there. I need it to be there for all users and I need it to run at logon and also have the ability to be run on demand if needed. Does anyone have any pointers?
I will also post screenshots of my setup. The batch file itself works, it just does not run with the scheduled task.
General:

Trigger:

Action:

